# How to get today's date from bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker, I want to use in-built functions of datepicker.
How can I use this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var fromDate = $('#fromdatepicker').datepicker();
    var toDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker(

    ).on('change', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    // here i need current date and do some calculation and then set again.
    console.log(toDate);
});
```

I use this https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html datepicker. Its works fine but I want to do some changes according to my need. I want to getCurrentDate and do some calculation and then set back again. How can I achieve this functionality using this datepicker.

Comment: http://www.daterangepicker.com/ It can help you.

Comment: You can use `new Date()` to get the current date in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
var toDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker(

).on('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

// here i need current date and do some calculation and then set again.

toDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('update',new Date());
console.log(toDate);

//if want to update again 
toDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('update','2016-08-16');
```